# Wildfly 8.1.0 Final and Netbeans 8.0: WildFly Application Server Start Failed. HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use

Tags: java, netbeans, wildfly-8

U have updated Wildfly from 8.0.0 FINAL to 8.1.0 FINAL. When I am trying to run the application in Netbeans 8.0, it fails starting and the following message is shown:

*WildFly Application Server Start Failed. HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use.*

When I am trying to manage the server from Netbeans menu, stop is disabled and killing hangs. I can kill the server from the system, but nothing changes. Still I cannot deploy/run the application from the environment anyhow.

It seems Netbeans starts the server twice.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I just found the problem. The previous problem happened when I have used "Update Existing 8.0.0.Final Install" from [Wildfly downloads](http://wildfly.org/downloads/) over the existing 8.0.0 installation.

When I desperately installed a fresh 8.1.0 installation, everything seems to work. So the problem is probably in the update package.