# Wildfly force redeploy NOT working / HTTP Connector port is already in use

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, wildfly

I am using NetBeans and when I run the server for the FIRST time (even if I restart my computer) it gives me an error: `"WildFly Application Server Start Failed. HTTP Connector port 8080 is already in use."`. When I run my project, the server should restart and my web app should redeploy to it, but that does not happen. Instead the mentioned error occurs.

Q: What is on the port 8080?

A: It's the Wildfly Application Server

Q: How do I know it's is the Wildfly on the port 8080?

A: I can access the admin wildfly console on the port 9990 and when I kill the process (through the terminal) that is listening on the 8080 port I can not access the admin wildfly console anymore.

Q: Did you configure wildfly as a service so it boots as soon as your computer boots?

A: No, I did not configure it that way. I even check in the services (it runs manually, not on boot)
[image: Proof that wildfly is not a automatic service]

People with the same problem:
[LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980932/wildfly-8-1-0-final-and-netbeans-8-0-wildfly-application-server-start-failed-h) , [LINK2](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/261471)

Comment: Unfortunately I already deleted the previous server, if it happens again I will try your provided solution and update my answer and question.

Comment: [1] OK. Regardless, there is no version information for any of the four products you tagged in your question, so please it update it accordingly. That information matters a lot for issues like this, and without the version details it is only possible to guess about potential causes of your problem. [2] Also, update your question with the stack trace if it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by deleting the wildfly server from my file system and downloading the same version from the Wildfly website. My guess is that some configuration file has become messed up for some reason. If anyone has a better solution please suggest it.